# Redirect Tomcat 9 servlet exception logs to log4j2

Tags: logging, log4j2, tomcat9

I am using log4j2 for logging my JSF web application.

1. I created log4j2.xml file under WEB-INF folder and configured it
2. Then added these dependencies to my pom.xml and used log4j2 in my application

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>2.13.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
       <version>2.13.3</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. I followed official guide for log4j2 integration with my Tomcat 9 here [Tomcat log4j2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-appserver/index.html)
4. I added `org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-jul:2.13.3` jar to the created lib directory in step 3 then configured Tomcat logging by adding the following code to setenv.bat in Tomcat/bin

   `set LOGGING_MANAGER=-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.logging.log4j.jul.LogManager`

Now I can get Tomcat log messages, my web application logs and JSF logs printed according to my log4j2 format.

The problem is, I am still getting `javax.servlet.ServletException` messages which do not follow my log4j2 log format. They seem to ignore my log4j2 configuration.

How can I fix this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that `javax.servlet.ServletException` messages were not handled by my application. Therefore they are not formatted according to my log4j2 configuration. I have solved this issue by creating a custom JSF exception handler and logging catched exceptions with log4j2.